# Ошибка при установе tesseract orc - Python

Tags: python

Когда устанавливаю `tesseact` через `pip` выдается такая ошибка:

```
C:\Users\admin>pip install tesseract-ocr
Collecting tesseract-ocr
  Using cached tesseract-ocr-0.0.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: cython in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from tesseract-ocr)
Installing collected packages: tesseract-ocr
  Running setup.py install for tesseract-ocr ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-fnr23yhx\\tesseract-ocr\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-467cet62-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
    file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
    running build_ext
    building 'tesseract_ocr' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /EHsc /Tptesseract_ocr.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\tesseract_ocr.obj
    tesseract_ocr.cpp
    tesseract_ocr.cpp(558): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'leptonica/allheaders.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-fnr23yhx\\tesseract-ocr\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-467cet62-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-fnr23yhx\tesseract-ocr\
```

Если ставить через установщик, то все равно при запуске кода на питоне:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

img = Image.open('pic11.png')
img.load()
i = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

выдается ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/admin/IdeaProjects/poker/.idea/2.py", line 8, in <module>
    i = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 122, in image_to_string
    config=config)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 46, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 992, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225927/pytesseract-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

Comment: `tesseract_ocr` модуль не имеет отношения к pytesseract. Чтобы pytesseract работал необходимо [tesseract установить](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki#windows)

Comment: Оказалось надо прописать пусть к `tesseract pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract'`

Comment: @MarkAmbrazhevich [readme](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/master/README.rst) об этом явно говорит. Если думаете, что нашли решение, вы можете опубликовать его как свой ответ — [это явно приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: моего рейтинга пока не достаточно для этого